# Creating a graph with multiple X axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph in Excel that I'd like to replicate in R if it's even possible. I am new to R, so any guidance will be appreciated.
So my data looks like this

[image: Excel data]

I can include the file if anyone wants it.

Then I have this graph:
[image: Graph Image]

I'd like to plot the same graph as in the Excel file but using R. So, is there a way to have a kind of subset for the x-axis values that belong to the main value?

I looked through the ggplot documentation and [How to plot side-by-side with sub labels and without space between subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858250/how-to-plot-side-by-side-with-sub-labels-and-without-space-between-subplots), but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome!  Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: That said, I'd look at the `ggplot2` package and the `geom_bar` and `geom_histogram` functions in particular.  The `fill` and `position` aesthetics will be relevant.  Alternatively, you could search stackoverflow for "dodged bar chart" or similar.

Comment: @Limey, thanks for your help. I didn't know of the term "dodged bar chart", so that greatly improved the results. Thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be helpful

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(ACI:SB) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), as.factor)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = R, y = value, fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", width=0.75)+
  facet_wrap(~A, nrow=1, strip.position="bottom") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  labs(fill="", y="", x="")
```

Produces:

[image]

If you want "to speak R with Excel accent" and convert this nice plot into a default excel plot, then you can add at the end of the plot `theme_excel_new()` from ggtheme package

```
library(ggthemes)
... + 
theme_excel_new()
```

It'll give the following plot

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(A = c(25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 250, 
250, 250), R = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R1", "R2", 
"R3", "R1", "R2", "R3"), ACI = c(2.94, 1.91, 8.86, 5.03, 8.77, 
1.89, 7.58, 7.24, 9.44, 5.48, 7.12, 3.89), PB = c(1.01, 9.27, 
2.83, 5.91, 1.1, 8.41, 3.18, 7.83, 2.68, 2.19, 5.17, 2.69), NB = c(1.81, 
5.19, 5.63, 1.29, 2.56, 7.18, 9.61, 1, 7.63, 9.48, 8.19, 3.08
), Bca = c(6.5, 9.53, 9.54, 3.4, 2.62, 1.65, 3.22, 5.1, 9.24, 
5.11, 2.58, 0.46), SB = c(4.18, 8.54, 3.47, 1.31, 3.74, 6.31, 
3.9, 6.9, 6.89, 5.55, 4.3, 4.53), `round(2)` = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: hey, thanks fr your answer. I have one small question, is it possible to choose the colors for the bars, I would like to have them as different shades of grayscale if that's possible. Thanks :))

Comment: Sure! just add `scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `geom_bar(position = "dodge")` or `facet_wrap()` to achieve your desired results. Please note that you'll need to name all your variables before plotting as it looks like the first two columns of your dataframe do not have names.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

# make a nested dataframe for example purposes
df <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "rowname") %>%
  select(c(1:5)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(rowname)) %>%
  head(n = 20)

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~rowname, nrow = 1) # use facet_wrap to display nestedness
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = rowname, y = value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]